# Height of image not always set when inserting with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have set of items (thumbnail  images) in middle that on hover fire more info and big images in side bar.
When i use code below, *sometimes* the height of image in sidebar is 0. While going to different thumbnail and coming back sets height properly.

```
//this code is run on hover
   var maxHeight=140;
   $.each(bigimages, function(index,el){
      var url = $(this).html(); //each of bigimages class have content of text url

      var newli = $('<li><img class="banner-img" src="'+url+'" ></li>');
      $(".banner ul").append(newli).promise().done(function(){

          console.log("img "+newli.find("img")[0].height); //here sometimes is 0

          if(newli.find("img")[0].height>maxHeight){
                                    maxHeight=newli.find("img")[0].height;

                                }
                            });
});
```

**EDIT**
Big images always exists so why this code shows 0 as height?

Comment: What is the question???

Comment: @codenoir - i edited with  question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the new HTML to the `ul` element, but this doesn't mean that the image is loaded immediately.  If you read the `height` property before the image's `onload` event fires, you'll get that zero.  Consider attaching some code to the image's `onload` event, and have that code consume the `height` property.  Something like this:

```
//this code is run on hover
var maxHeight = 140;
$.each(bigimages, function(index, el) {
    var url = $(this).html(); //each of bigimages class have content of text url

    var newli = $('<li><img class="banner-img" src="' + url + '" ></li>');
    var image = newli.find("img");
    image.on("load", function() {
        console.log("img " + $(this)[0].height); //here sometimes is 0

        if ($(this)[0].height > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this)[0].height;
        }
    });
    $(".banner ul").append(newli).promise().done(function() {
        //anything else you need to do after promise
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this)[0].height` == `this.height`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the image hasn't finished loading when you try to access the `height` property. You could hook up some preloading of the image to achieve this using your sample code as a base:

```
$(".banner ul").append(newli).promise().done(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = newli.find('img').attr('src');
    img.onload = function()
    {
        conosle.log( this.height );

        if( this.height > maxHeight )
        {
            maxHeight = this.height;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Max height for one images is  500px and other 140px. Long story is that `.banner` is really a  carousel slider. So in order to show images in carousel i need its height to not show only part of images.

Comment: @Mike Sorry, spotted the logic I had missed. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you attempt to check the height immediately after the `<li>` and `<img>` are added to the DOM. At this stage, the image is not loaded.

As you're using jQuery, attach a `load()` event handler to the image.

Answer (score -2):

check if the element is loaded if it does not then it will return '0'

Use window load

```
$(window).load(function(){
//put your code here, window load runs after document ready.
});
```